# A walk in a matrix

Tags: matrices

Given a binary matrix $M$, a cell $M(i,j)=1$ if its free, else it is blocked.  We are also given a string $L$ denoting the commands for the walk. If $L='UDLR'$, it means go up, then down, then left and then right.
We can only walk on free cells. So if next command is to go up, and that cell is blocked or it is out of the matrix, we stop.
Now for each '**free cell**', we need to find the maximum steps of the command that it will be able to follow if we start our walk from it.

I planned to make a list of coordinates $(+x_i,+y_i)$ that the string $L$ takes us to. So if I start from free cell at $(x,y)$, I need to find the blocked cell at position $(x+x_i,y+y_i)$ where $i$ is as small as possible. Am I going right or theres some better approach.

Comment: Are you looking for an algorithm here?

Comment: @SantanaAfton Yes.

Comment: Say I have a $2$-by-$2$ matrix with all ones, and I give the command $URDLURDL \ldots URDLURDL$. Does that mean that the lower-left free cell has infinite steps in your system? Or, if any matrix has two $1$s adjacent (say, one above the other), does the command $UDUD\ldots UDUD$ mean the lower cell has infinite steps?

Comment: @SantanaAfton Yes, we can perform steps as long as the command is. So if command length is 100, we can perform 100 steps as we never reach a blocked cell midway.

Comment: Oh, I see, sorry. I thought your question was about the longest valid command that could be given from any free cell. Your question is asking about when a command is interrupted, correct?

Comment: @SantanaAfton For every free cell, I need to find when a command is interrupted.